# USB Drive shows up in Device Manager but is not accessible from File Explorer/My Computer

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb

I have a USB drive that shows up as **Lexmark USB** in *Safely Remove Hardware* but I cannot find it in My Computer. The only things that show up in My Computer are the computer's hard drive and *Network Places.*

I am running Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium.

I have tried using the Windows Troubleshooter and that doesn't do anything. It gets stuck in a loop from "Checking device status --> Checking device something --> Checking issues with device --> Checking device status"

The USB is recognized perfectly fine on another machine running Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on another machine being able to read from it fine, it sounds to me like it is most likely set to dynamic and/or a drive letter is simply not being assigned.

Click Start and right click on `Computer` and click `Manage`. On the Computer Management Window, go to `Disk Management`.

From here, you should be able to see a row/line in the bottom section of the page that shows your drive. Simply right click on the volume and select `Change Drive Letter and Paths`

[image]

On the dialog that comes up, select `Add`, and the drive you want.

If you can't get this far/If it says `Dynamic` on the left (where it shows basic in my screenshot), simply right click and chose `initalise`, however if this is the case, Disk Management would have said that a dynamic disk was detected when you first opened it.

---

Just to note: 
There is also a licensing restriction on dynamic disks that I just can't remember off by heart or from doing a quick Google. I believe it was where the home/basic editions couldn't read them... but, I have a feeling that was just with Windows XP.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Had no idea I had to assign it a Drive Letter for it to be recognized, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome, And... You don't always have to do it... There are some weird situations where it occurs. Sometimes it can be bad tools/AV that intercept the mount, other times it can be a registry conflict, or, I remember a patch a while ago (that was fixed) which stopped auto mount.... Go to an elevated command prompt (right click cmd and do `Run as administratior`, then type `Diskpart`, and then type `automount`, if it says ¬Automatic mounting of new volumes is disabled` just type `automount enable`.

Comment: This happens most often when the drive letter used to mount on the last computer is not available for use on the current one (ie. There is another drive already using that letter).

Comment: @James - Where on the drive is this remembered/stored? ... First time I am hearing of it, I could swear I get different letters on different machines - but, it is interesting/makes sense and I want to look in to this!

Comment: @William: I'm not sure, I've never looked into it, but I noticed the behavior after a few years of using portable drives.  I suspect it's stored with the partition info.

Comment: @James - no worries. I have just seen this issue at complete random and never really looked at the logic behind it! What you suggested makes as good sense as anything else!

Comment: What do I do if I click "Change Drive Letter and Paths" and it says it cannot find the file specified?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that your USB drive was not assigned a valid drive letter. To fix this:

1. Right-click *My Computer*, then click **Manage**
2. Click **Disk Management** in left pane.
3. Right-click your USB drive and choose **Change Drive Letter and Paths...**
4. Select an available drive letter from the list.

Answer (score -1):

I was connected through a USB Extender while i had this issue, i Solved it by connecting Directly to a different port in The Back Pannel of the PC (Even the Front pannel USB was showing the same issue) , So please try changing the Ports you are connecting before Concluding its an Issue of HDD or Its Controller

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).