# Can't assign drive letter to USB drive

Tags: usb, windows-11

I can't assign a drive letter to a USB drive which is visible in device manager / computer management but is not accessible in the file explorer. I tried following the steps in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/859819/422053), but when trying to assign a drive letter it stops with the error message shown in the screenshot below.

Has anyone got some idea of what might be going on here, and how I can check what is on the disk?

I have a vague suspicion that the drive might be an installer for Linux Mint, but I think it should still be possible to view the contents in windows? Am I completely off base here?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disk 1 has only one partition of 230 GB, which is marked as being EFI.
Disk Management will not touch an EFI partition.

You may use `diskpart` to change EFI system partition ID (type)
and set it to be marked as a data partition, to be able to
manipulate the partition.

Here is how to do that :

- Run diskpart
- `list disk` to displays all disks
- `sel disk X`
- `list partition` to display all partitions
- `sel partition Y` for the EFI partition
- `SET ID=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7`

The above advice is for GPT disks. For MBR disks, the ID is `0xEF`.

Comment: Oh, from what I get from a quick look at wikipedia, that seems to make sense from it being a boot disk or similar. Will changing the system partition ID mean that it'd no longer work as a boot disk? Also, if I am only interested in getting access to the disk so I can format it for use as data storage, I guess the command to diskpart would be slightly different? Anyway, thanks a lot for your reply - you certainly cleared up the main gist of my question! :-)

Comment: Once the partition type is changed to data, you may do anything you like with that disk (except boot).

Answer (score 2):

If you see that message Windows Disk Administrator is getting confused about the content of the USB stick.
This occaissionally happens when you are reformatting/repartioning disks.

Reboot the computer and try again. This usually fixes the problem.

Or try DISkPART from the command line. DISKPART is often more reliable in this regard and has more options than the Disk Admin GUI.
(And in DISKPART start with a CLEAN command to make sure you do the re-partition with a clean slate.)

EDIT after seeing Harrymc answer posted in parallel to mine:
I missed the EFI partition bit.
This may necessitate using DISKPART anyway, but the Disk Admin GUI getting confused is happening as well in your screenshot and will in most cases still need a reboot to fix.